# My app does not load an activity on the device

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My android app links to a new activity to allow a user to create their profile and save the strings they use to a firebase database. However, the activity loads but is blank as shown below. This issue only seemed to arise after I added functionality to save user data to firebase.
[blank activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e5YY.jpg)

```
    package com.example.eventfeed;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.PersistableBundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class CreateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String INTEREST_KEY = "interest";
    public static final String NAME_KEY = "name";
    private DocumentReference mDocRef = RegisterActivity.getmDocRef();
    private Button createBtn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.create_profile_layout);
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Create Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       EditText interestsView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interests);
        EditText nameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_name);

        String interests = interestsView.getText().toString();
        String name= nameView.getText().toString();

        Map<String, Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<>();
        mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("users/" + ActivityLoginEmail.getEmailStr() + "/profileInfo");
        dataToSave.put(INTEREST_KEY, interests);
        dataToSave.put(NAME_KEY, name);
        mDocRef.set(dataToSave);

        createBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createProfileBtn);
       createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(CreateProfileActivity.this, Profile.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });



    }
}
```

The xml files that format the page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/create_profile_layout"
tools:context=".CreateProfileActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout">

    </include>

    <include layout="@layout/create_profile_content"></include>



</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Create profile activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".CreateProfileActivity"
android:id="@+id/create_profile_content"
tools:showIn="@layout/create_profile_layout">

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vibe_concert" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"

        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vibe_image" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/profile_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="158dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="156dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="228dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.553"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/interest_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="224dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/profile_interest"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        tools:text="Interests" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/interests"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.091" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.679"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.544" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createProfileBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.835"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/interests"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.473"
        tools:text="Create Profile" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The method that is called to send the user to the create profile activity

```
    private void LoginUser(){
            setEmailStr(email.getText().toString().trim());
             String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();
             mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailStr, Password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new 
                                  OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(ActivityLoginEmail.this, "Create 
     Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            setCurrent_user_db(false);
                            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLoginEmail.this, 
    CreateProfileActivity.class));

                        }else {
                            setCurrent_user_db(true);
                            Toast.makeText(ActivityLoginEmail.this, "couldn't login",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

EDIT:After changing the xml file to a simple one with just a single button and adding a toast command to print if the activity loads nothing happens. Therefore the problem is most likely not within the xml files.

EDIT2:I found the solution by removing the PersistableBundle parameter from my oncreate method. Not exactly sure what this does to begin with if anyone would like to elaborate.

```
 public class CreateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String INTEREST_KEY = "interest";
public static final String NAME_KEY = "name";
private DocumentReference mDocRef = RegisterActivity.getmDocRef();
private Button createBtn;

public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.create_profile_layout);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Create Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   EditText interestsView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interests);
    EditText nameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_name);

    String interests = interestsView.getText().toString();
    String name= nameView.getText().toString();

    Map<String, Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<>();
    mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("users/" + 
 ActivityLoginEmail.getEmailStr() + "/profileInfo");
    dataToSave.put(INTEREST_KEY, interests);
    dataToSave.put(NAME_KEY, name);
    mDocRef.set(dataToSave);

    createBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createProfileBtn);
   createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(CreateProfileActivity.this, Profile.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   });



}
}
```

Comment: why you have this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` twice in your xml?

Comment: did you have multiple root tag in xml?

Comment: @VadimEksler sorry the formatting looks strange but there are two different xml files create_profile_layout and create_profile_content, create_profile_content is including in create_profile_layout

Comment: and where is the code from `Profile` ...which does not even sound as if were an `Activity`?

Comment: Problem solved thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

try by moveing `finish()`  to the bottom of this condition

```
 if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        Toast.makeText(ActivityLoginEmail.this, "Create 
 Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        setCurrent_user_db(false);
                        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLoginEmail.this, 
CreateProfileActivity.class));
                         finish();

                    }
```